# How to filter by DBRef in CosmosDB for MongoDB?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, azure-cosmosdb-mongoapi

I am using Azure Cosmos DB for MongoDB. I have two collections: cars and parkings. A car knows what parking it is in via an `@DBRef` . I have the following document classes

```kotlin
@Document("cars")
data class CarDocument(

  @Id
  val id: String,

  @DBRef
  val parking: ParkingDocument?
}

@Document("parkings")
data class ParkingDocument(

  @Id
  val id: String

}
```

And the following spring data repositories:

```kotlin
@Repository
interface CarMongoRepository : MongoRepository<CarDocument, String> {
  fun findByParkingId(id: String): List<CarDocument>
}

@Repository
interface ParkingMongoRepository : MongoRepository<ParkingDocument, String>
```

When calling findByParkingId('some existent parking id'), it doesn't return any result because the actual filter that spring data sends to CosmosDB for MongoDB is

```json
{
  "parking": {
    "$ref": "parkings",
    "$id": "some existent parking id"
  }
}
```

I tested this filter in a real MongoDB and it works perfectly: it returns all cars that are parked in that parking. But when running it in CosmosDB for MongoDB, it doesn't match any car. I had to write the filter like this outside of Spring Data (Studio3T) in order to have a match:

```json
{ "parking._id" : "some existent parking id" }
```

But I can't get Spring Data to build the filter like this. Question: Do you know how to build the filter like this using Spring Data repositories? Or how to make CosmosDB for MongoDB understand the MongoDB's filter?

PS:
I tried to delete the `@DBRef` annotation, but I don't want to store duplicated parkings, because they are very big entities and it would be a nightmare to manage the integrity. Also there is an index in one of it's fields that would be nested as car.parking.code (which I removed from the previous example code to keep it minimal), which isn't allowed in CosmosDB.

Answer (score 0):

`DBRef` follows a defined structure in MongoDB. In case you need to move off that by using some other DB maybe also try to use the [Spring Data Module](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-java/tree/main/sdk/spring/azure-spring-data-cosmos) built for it.
If that's not an option, you can try using `@DocumentReference` instead of `@DBRef` to gain more control.